# My server ignores the .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, uri

I have a terrible problem: I have written rubbish within the *.htaccess* file, in order to break my web site, and cause an error 500. Result: nothing, nothing happens, the web site continues to be online.

That is, **the *.htaccess* file is ignored completely**. Why does this happen? I understand that this only has an answer: the Apache server is misconfigured. This is absolutely correct? Or are there other possible causes?

My file system: [image 1](http://pruebas-berkeley.hol.es/compartir/img/file-system-1.jpg) and [image 2](http://pruebas-berkeley.hol.es/compartir/img/file-system-2.jpg).

Originally the website was hosted on a folder within a server (mydomain.com/folder), and everything worked fine. Now I am migrating the website to another server, but within a subdomain. The features of the new server:

- **Subdomain:** domain.company.com
- **Apache:** 2.4.7 (*Ubuntu*)
- **Port:** 80
- **phpinfo:** Open [phpinfo](http://pruebas-berkeley.hol.es/compartir/txt/phpinfo.html)

**UPDATE.**

1) **DNS.** I checked my subdomain with http://whois.domaintools.com/ and http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx. I found no problems.

2) **.htaccess.** The file contains RewriteEngine on. RewriteBase is commented, because I don't know what to put when a subdomain. Anyway, no matter what I put in the file, it is completely ignored.

3) My **settings.php** has:

- $ Base_url = 'http://domain.company.com'; // NO trailing slash!
- There is not $base_path. Does not exist.

I cleared the cache Drupal. I cleared the browser cache. I truncate all tables that start with cache_.

**It does not work.** The file .htaccess remains ignored. This, I can not enable friendly URLs.

Comment: This is a common problem on shared-hosting environments. If you don't have access to your server to configure, you'll probably need to contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Sorry but server config questions are off-topic here unless they have a specific connection to Drupal - an .htaccess being ignored is something more general than that. Contacting your hosting provider would be the best solution

Answer (score 4):

This generally happens when your web server does not have access to make the overrides to your webroot.

Check if your `httpd.conf` file has something of the following format

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">
    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

The important piece above is `AllowOverride All`, which will make possible for *your* .htaccess file to override the settings.

If you cannot change the settings in this file, I would recommend you to create a `.conf` file specific to your site (e.g. `mysite.conf` using the default file `000-default`) in on of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` or `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, and modify the `<Directory>` tag to point to the root of your site.

Restart Apache in order to make this change visible. The site should now be able to pick up your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Ajit I am agree with you, but on apache server the .htaccees is completely ignored on his case, in generally it is no dependent on the mysie.conf file. Isn't it?
BTW +1 for the answer.

Comment: @Shubham : As mentioned in answer, the `.htaccess` is not able to override the configurations probably because of the value set in the `httpd.conf` which has the settings for all of your webroot (eg. localhost). I suggested to create the own conf file for the purpose of making the change only for one site. Thanks for the +1 btw ;)

Comment: @ Ajit thanks for sharing information. Can you please let me know the .htaccess case with NGINX sever. .htaccess file does not work with NGINX server.

Comment: It seems an excellent idea to create my own file .conf.
I only find one small problem: I do not have access to these folders: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled or /etc/apache2/sites-available.
I do not even have access to cPanel. I have only SFTP access. This is my webroot: [see](http://pruebas-berkeley.hol.es/compartir/img/filezilla.jpg).
Obviously, I can not restart Apache.

Comment: @GeorgeBerkeley I that case, I would suggest to talk to your hosting provider and ask them to make those changes at least for your webroot.

Comment: I spoke with my hosting. They said that everything was properly configured. Suddenly, just like that, the file was recognized. Obviously everything was a problem with the hosting. **Note to myself:** never trust blindly in the words of the people in the hosting.

Comment: @GeorgeBerkeley Yep. They might have fixed it for your domain before saying everything is fine. Anyways, good to know that you got your issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

1) DNS setup properly

2) .htaccess - Look for the RewriteBase setting AND RewriteEngine on

3) settings.php - Look for $base_url and $base_path

Don't forget to clear the cache after you change these settings. If you can't access the site, use drush cc all or login to your database and truncate all tables that start with cache_ (sometimes clearing the cache still leaves persistent entries).

Comment: Can you edit your question for how you have your sites directory setup?  I would comment above but my rep isn't high enough yet.  You can up vote me so I can comment above ;)

Comment: @george-berkeley I am also trying to understand your question.  Are you trying to break your site?